FromServices not working with WebApplicationFactory<Program>
I have the following NUnit test using Asp.net core 8.
public class DevextremeTests 
{
    private WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public DevextremeTests()
    {
        _factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_get_grid()
    {
        using (var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var companyServices = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<CompanyServices>(); //not null
            var autoQuery = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<IAutoQueryDb>(); //not null
            // companyServices.AutoQuery is null 
        }
    }
}

companyServices populates but on that service are other services like
[FromServices]
public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; } //null
[FromServices]
public ApplicationDbContext Ef { get; set; } //null

In the main application the nested services loads fine.
If I switch from using [FromServices] to constructor injection then it works and the nested services populate.
Why is [FromServices] not working with WebApplicationFactory<Program>()?

Because the FromServicesAttribute provides ASP.NET Core specific binding:

Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using the request services.

The build-in DI does not support property injection:

We recommend using the built-in container unless you need a specific feature that it doesn't support, such as:

Property injection
...


And the mechanism via the attribute is ASP.NET Core request specific for controller actions, minimal API handlers or Razor pages on per-request basis (i.e. web request). And you don't have request here, just a "plain" DI container.
